# Common ways to find sub string in oracle and sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, substring

Hi I have below sql query where I am using SUBSTR in oracle, I need to modify SUBSTR so that this query should work for both oracle and sql server

Note: in oracle we have SUBSTR and in sql server we have SUBSTRING, LEFT, RIGHT but I need common query that should work in both oracle an sql server data base.

```
SELECT INA.LOCATION_CODE,INA.ACCT_NUM,INA.STATE_ENTRY_DATE,FP.NUM_INA_DYS_BF_PUR FROM INACTIVE_ACCOUNT INA  
            LEFT JOIN FUNCTIONAL_AREA FA ON INA.LOCATION_CODE=FA.LOCATION_CODE AND SUBSTR(INA.RETURN_TO_STE_CODE,0,1)=FA.FUNC_STATE_ENTR_KY
            JOIN FUNC_AREA_PARAM FP ON FA.GUID=FP.PARN_GUID;
```

Answer (score 0):

There isn't such a function.  Trying to write code that works across different databases *with exactly the same syntax* is a fool's errand.  There are too many subtle differences between most databases that it is generally not possible.

That said, you can do something in this case:

```
ON INA.LOCATION_CODE = FA.LOCATION_CODE AND
   INA.RETURN_TO_STE_CODE LIKE CONCAT(FA.FUNC_STATE_ENTR_KY, '%')
```

This should work in both databases.  That is because you are lucky.